# How to successfully delete a Facebook message that you sent someone from their inbox remotely

Tags: facebook-messenger

I sent a message to someone that I didn't mean to, although they haven't seen it yet. It was very personal and I don't want them to read it. Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete message from someone else inbox, it has seen or not that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of deleting your message from your friend's Chat Inbox or from a Conversation once it is sent. Messages will only be deleted from your Chat Inbox or Conversation.

The official article from [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/192631610782421?sr=2&query=delete%20message&sid=0b0GxF9GVjdhXfPCo):

> ### How do I delete messages or a conversation?
>
> You can delete messages one at a time, or you can delete an entire conversation.
>
> [...]
>
> **Note**: Once you choose to delete a conversation, this can't be undone.
>
> Keep in mind that deleting a message or conversation from your inbox
>   won't delete it from your friend's inbox. **It isn't possible to delete
>   sent or received messages from a friend's inbox**.